# Perl DBI/Mysql Unicode Bug

Tags: mysql, perl, unicode

I'm not sure if it's a bug or I'm doing something wrong:

I read data per

```
open my $fh, "<:encoding(iso-latin1)", $file or die "Failed to open $file: $!";
```

$file is definitely in iso-latin1.

Then I have a mysql table which is

```
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=53072 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I check the connection settings:

```
$dbh->prepare("show variables");
```

Which gives

```
character_set_client, latin1
character_set_connection, latin1
character_set_database, latin1
character_set_filesystem, binary
character_set_results, latin1
character_set_server, latin1
character_set_system, utf8
```

So to me everything should be fine:

- Table is iso-latin1
- Data was iso-latin1 (should be perl internal character format now)
- Connection info shows the right settings
- Output to STDOUT (terminal is iso-latin1) is correct

But: Data in table is plain utf8 (most probably perl's internal format in this case).

Did I miss something is this maybe a bug in DBI/DBD::mysql?

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that you're right and this data is in Perl's internal character format. The sequence goes like this.

- Data in input file stored as Latin-1 bytes
- Data read from input file and auto-converted to Perl characters because of the encoding option on your `open` statement
- Data sent to MySQL as Perl characters
- MySQL slightly confused by getting UTF8 instead of Latin-1, but stores it anyway as best it can

The step your missing is to encode you Perl characters back into Latin-1 before sending them to the database. The obvious solution is to call `encode('iso-885901', $string)` on every value you sent to the database. It would be nice if there was some kind auto-encode option. But I can't find one.

Of course, if your data is all going to be Latin-1, then you could consider just ignoring any decoding/encoding issues. It should all just work without that complication.

Comment: I understand that encoding would probably solve the issue but shouldn't perl handle this autmatically? I mean there is no ambiguity here: Perl knows that the databse expects iso latin bytes and not utf8 characters.

Comment: Why do you think that Perl knows that?